# NVIDIA GTX 980 Ti, no CUDA showing in Blender on a Mac

Tags: modeling

Ok, perhaps I'm a moron, that's entirely possible, but I thought the 980Ti was CUDA.

Blender shows GPU as default (which is grayed). I go into system settings, it doesn't show Cuda.

However I check the "FlipFluids addon" and this clearly shows the GPU is seen.

I'm on Mac 10.12.6, 12-core, running Blender 2.79b.

Any suggestions?

I've searched Google, NVidia website, reinstalled drivers, deleted Blender/reinstalled.

And when I switch to OpenCL it crashes.

I'm stumped.
thanks,
alldaron

Comment: "I'm on Mac": well, there's your problem..you probably need nvidia cuda driver for macos.

Comment: Yes, I have that installed, 
CUDA Driver Version: 396.64 --- 
GPU Driver Version: 378.05.05.25f01 --- 
NVIDIA Web Driver 378.05.05.25.f01

Comment: That [378.05.05.25f01 driver](http://www.nvidia.com/download/driverResults.aspx/120845/en-us) supports only gpus up to GTX 680. You probably need [9.0.197 version](http://www.nvidia.com/object/macosx-cuda-9.0.197-driver.html) that is the last for Sierra 10.12.x Newer versions require OSX 10.13.x.

Comment: Awesome, thank you!!       ugh all this is so annoyingly confusing.

Comment: Installed, now mac shows: CUDA Driver Version: 387.178 --- GPU Driver Version: 10.18.5 (378.05.05.25f01)